# subtract two textboxes in ssrs from diff tables

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to build a report like this

[image]

In this report 2015 and 2016 columns are from different tables and I need the difference of both of them as result in another table the data set for 2015 and 2016 are also different. The data is pulled from cube. I tried this expression to get the result

ReportItems!textbox10.Value-ReportItems!textbox5.Value here textbox 10(2016 column) and textbox5(2015 column)  but when I do this calculation I'm getting this result set

[image]

Comment: How are you getting the datasets? Embedded SQL Query, Stored Procedure? Can you show the 2 different queries?

Comment: I'm getting the data from the cube it is MDX query

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can reference a textbox with an expression like this:

```
=ReportItems!TextBoxList1.Value
```

However, I would strongly caution against this as it usually goes against best practices. Textboxes in tables are meant to be dynamic based on the grouping you define. It would be best to refer to the actual values from the dataset using the `Lookup` function. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx) for more info on that.

Edit based on feedback:
There are two ways you can go about this.

1. Remove the filters from the query and apply the filters on the tables. This way, you can use table grouping to separate out the numbers, but still compare them to the total. The difference expression would look something like this:

   ```
   =Sum(Fields!Amt.Value) - Sum(Fields!Amt.Value, "RowGroupName")
   ```
2. With your existing structure, use a lookup like this:

   ```
   =Fields!Amt2.Value - Lookup(Fields!ID1.Value, Fields!ID2.Value, Fields!Amt1.Value, "Dataset1Name")
   ```

Comment: But the lookup set doesnt allow to do calculations right?

Comment: @lauri `Lookup` is different than `LookupSet`. You can do calculations with values that you Lookup in expressions.

Comment: Can you suggest how you think I need to write the expression in my case?

Comment: @lauri do these dates all come from the same cube? Usually the date is a dimension.

Comment: Yes they come from same cube but they have different filters that is why they have different data sets

Comment: @lauri I updated the answer to give more specific options